# How did they do the sea floor in Exodus: Gods and Kings?

Tags: effects, exodus-gods-and-kings

The sea floor rendering in "Exodus: Gods and Kings" was really amazing:

[image: Red Sea parted]

How did they do that 3D rendering? Where did they get the models? What sofware? What was the studio that did it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MPC studios, along with Scanline VFX was the company responsible for creating the visual [effects](http://www.maacindia.com/blog/index.php/exodus-gods-and-kings-vfx-breakdown/)

> the Red Sea remains one of the most iconic scenes in the film. Scott &
>   his CGI team had the daunting task of living up to expectations. The
>   team meticulously created this famous biblical miracle under visual
>   effects supervisor Jessica Norman. The scene was filmed at a beach on
>   Fuerteventura, one of the Canary Islands off the northwest coast of
>   Africa. **MPC** **studios, along with Scanline VFX**, used a wave
>   animation rig to create the catastrophic ocean waves. **Scanline**
>   **VFX used their in-house fluid effects software –** ***Flowline*** – to make this scene a cinematic delight. **Close-ups of the actual
>   beach water were used to film people** **fleeing across the sea bed**.
>   Except Christian Bale, Joel Edgerton & 30-40 people in the background,
>   everything else including the water heading toward infinity, horses,
>   and the **40,000 people crossing the red sea were
>   computer-generated.**